# Tomcact 404 error after deploying my WAR into Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I have deployed my WAR into Tomcat 8.5.32 and getting 404 error after successful deployment.

This is a GWT application using spring security and Maven.

I have checked my context path,URL pattern and the index.jsp is having redirection to my . The flow is also as expected.

```
<display-name>*21 Portal</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/infrastructure.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/resource.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/integration.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/service.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Getting the error shown below:

```
404 Error
404 /dzd/login.htm Page Not Available or Internal Error
Please Contact Administrator
```

what went wrong and what i missed which has resulted in this above error.

Comment: Please verify if you are using index.jsp page or a index.htm page.

Comment: What is the name of your WAR?

Comment: The name of war is dzd.war

Comment: @PriyataRajput could you share your `web.xml` as well as the complete `url` you are using to access the `login.htm` page?

Comment: http://localhost:7070/dzd/login.htm ---> using this URL as for this application I have to rename it before deploying to my environment.

Comment: @PriyataRajput I think your url is incomplete. Usually there is also a url-pattern associated to servlet which serves the request. This `<url pattern>` is specified in `web.xml` file under `<servlet-mapping>` tag. So the url for access is : `http://localhost:7070/war-name/url-pattern/login.htm`

Comment: This doesn't worked. I had some issue with spring security and proxy. Now I am facing issue : Error creating bean with name 'delegateAdmin': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.